# Linux command to sort according to second word/character

Tags: perl, shell

I have a linux file whose content is as below:

```
hey this 
is just
sample file
```

I want to :

**1.**  sort the three lines according to the second word so the output should be :

```
sample file
is just
hey this
```

**2.**  sort the three lines according to the second character of second line, so the output would be :

```
hey this 
sample file
is just
```

Is there anyway i can run a perl/unix command on command line(doesnt matter using pipes)?

Comment: you can use this command `cat sample.txt | sort -k 2`

Comment: Or `sort -k2 sample.txt`, or `sort -k2 < sample.txt`

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer for both the questions:

For sorting by second word: `sort -k2 myfile`

For sorting by second character of second word `sort -k2.3 myfile`

Comment: Using the `-b` option makes the field offset more sane: `sort -b -k 2.2`